# prefix routing not working in cakephp2.4.1 Through not found error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have fresh downloaded cakephp 2.4.1 and added prefix routing in core.php

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

And added following routes in routes.php file

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));

Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
```

when i goto localhost/cakephp2.4/admin it gives

```
Not Found

The requested URL /cakephp2.4/admin was not found on this server.
```

I have checked that core.php have Debug Level 2

```
 Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

Don't know how to figure out this issue.

Comment: Are you calling    CakePlugin::routes();   after your routes-configuration?

Comment: I ahve added an die("hiii"); in routes.php file .  EVEN localhost/cakephp2.4/admin  shows the not found error

Comment: But you can normaly reach that localhost/pages/index action?

Comment: @nedstark How did you solve the problem? i am having the same problem.

Comment: @Console Are you running your application on localhost?

Comment: @Console I followed the instructions here   http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html   and  it worked.Look like cakephp wasn't allowed to edit Url Rewriting